# Ubuntu 17.04 does not hibernate correctly

Tags: 17.04, hibernate

I updated to Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty) and found hibernation wouldn't initiate. After ensuring that SecureBoot was off, I checked the partitions and found that there was no "official" swap partition. Therefore, I created one of equal size to my RAM and hibernate began operating. However, hibernate does not save my disk state, nor does it power off my computer. My power LED is still on and my fans running. It stalls at this step, after disabling mouse and keyboard, leaving me no choice but to shutdown by holding the power button. Once I start up Ubuntu again, it is as if it is simply a cold startup. I have searched for solutions in a few places, but could not find my problem. Please help

Comment: Possibly useful: [Ubuntu 17.04 - doesn't have a swap partition?](//askubuntu.com/q/910298) and possibly my answer here which I updated for hibernation on 17.04 using a swapfile [How can I hibernate on Ubuntu 16.04?](//askubuntu.com/a/821122)

Comment: @Zanna I have a swap partition that is actually being recognized by the system. Also, my problem is that hibernate doesn't completely shut down my computer, which your other article doesn't seem to address. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Hmm it has suggestions/links for debugging any issues with hibernation... there are probably many better posts about it though.

Comment: Well, it turned out there was yet another system update rewriting a profile for TuxOnIce. Once that was downloaded and installed correctly, it seems to have fixed the problem. I really wish they would put more prominent notifications in.

Comment: oh that's interesting. Would you consider adding it as an answer to help others? Or do you consider the problem non-reproducible?